# How Can I Implement a Multiclass Multilabel Classification in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

Suppose I have some set of input outputs like below:

```
input1  : [0 1 1 1 0 ... 1]
output1 : [1 2 2 3 ... 3 3 1 2 2]
...
```

the inputs are always **0 or 1** and the outputs are always **1 or 2 or 3**

how can I create a neural network in keras that can fit on these input outputs?

```
checkpoint_path = 'p-multilable.h5' 
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, mode='max', monitor='acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(1000,activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),
        keras.layers.Dense(300,),
        keras.layers.Dense(300,),
        keras.layers.Dense(53)]) 


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=1000, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

I tried normalizing output to **0 0.5 1** but it didn't help.

I tried various loss functions

I tried defining custom loss function

I tried many network architectures

in most cases it has acc of about 0.09

in theory it is no more than binary sets and should not be hard but I cannot find the proper way

Answer (score 0):

For your last classification layer, you should give it a `softmax` activation. This activation is used for classifications. It may require you to one hot encode your outputs though.

Comment: Can a softmax activation handle multilabel classification?

Comment: What do you mean by multilabel?

Comment: as per the example in the multilabel there are multiple none zero outputs for a given input. it's the opposite of one hot encode

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
there seems to be two methods to overcome the problem:

**1- The Ugly Method:**

Using two outputs for each number, so the **1** will becomes **01**, **2** becomes **10** and **3** becomes **11**, for the **00** you can use it for any of the above or even calculate the precision

**2- The Not So Ugly Method:**

Using three One Hot Encoded for each output so the **1** becomes **001**, the **2** becomes **010** and the **3** becomes **100**

you can also use a 2D **[x][3]** input so you can get a 2D output **[y][3]** but it seems not necessary